# grep to see lines that start with duplicate alpha characters

Tags: linux, grep

I’m trying to use grep to find lines that start with duplicate alpha characters (a-zA-z). What would be the proper grep command to accomplish this?

This is what I have so far:

```
grep -E '[:alpha:]' $lines1
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the expression you seek:

```
^([A-Za-z])\1
```

As shown here:

```
$ grep -E '^([A-Za-z])\1' input
aardvark
$ grep -E '^([[:alpha:]])\1' input
aardvark
$ cat input
apple
aardvark
bookkeeper
```

To expand on the expression:

```
 NODE                     EXPLANATION
 ^                        the beginning of the string
 (                        group and capture to \1:
   [A-Za-z]                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
 )                        end of \1
 \1                       what was matched by capture \1
```

Comment: The version with `[:alpha:]` works with accented characters (according to the current locale), the one with `[A-Za-z]` doesn't.  FWIW.